# Is there a way in JMeter to start threads at set periods of time?

Tags: multithreading, csv, jmeter

I'm trying to write a JMeter test that reads a CSV data set and waits a set amount of time until starting the next thread. I tried using a Constant Timer but that doesn't start timing until after the previous call is complete. I want to simulate an addition user starting to hit an URL, might be different, but it could be the same. (The CSV data contains a list of URLs and the time between each call being hit from our logs).

Is there a way to do this. I've tried several options including
1) Number of thread = total number of users over set amount of time and Ramp-up time = time span of X number of users on site
2) Number of thread = 1 with a loop waiting the different amounts of time from CSV

I'm stumped.

Comment: JMeter works on thread-based model where each thread will wait for a response before sending subsequent requests. If you want a pause or maintain the pace, you can use several samplers such as Throughput Shaping Timer, Ultimate Thread Group, Stepping Thread Group from [JMeter plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/).

Answer (score 0):

In thread-group, there is a field Ramp up, which allows you to control after how many seconds a new user will start hitting the url.

Example:
you want 2 concurrent users to hit a same url. 2nd user should start hitting after 10 seconds.
Go to thread group and add:

No of threads: 2

Rampup: 10

Loopcount: [as per requirement]

If number of threads are more than 2 and you want each user to pitch in after 10 seconds, then, use:

Number of threads: n

Rampup: n*10

Loopcount: [as required]